# PhD Recommendation Letter from Bachelor Supervisor

Tags: phd, recommendation-letter, supervision

I am currently doing my Master in physics in the University X. Previously, I did my Bachelor in the University Y. I am applying for a PhD positions that requires two recommendation letters. The supervisor of my Master Thesis agreed to write for me a letter.

For the second one, I could ask a professor with which I did a course and a seminar in my current university X, or I could ask the supervisor of my Bachelor thesis when I was in Y. Who do you think is better? I add some information: I finished my Bachelor in physics three years ago (I hope he remembers me). I worked around six months for the Bachelor thesis and at the end it was awarded the highest grade. So in principle I would ask him, but I do not know if it is okay for PhD applications to have letters from the Bachelor.

Comment: "I hope he remembers me" - That is indeed the important question. If he remembers you as a strong student, his letter would definitely be helpful. If he doesn't remember you,, his letter might not be strong, which could be detrimental to your application. The bottom line is: when you ask him, make sure to ask if he can write a *strong* letter of recommendations.

Comment: Spend some effort to reconnect with the earlier professor. They will likely support you strongly, but might need a bit of a nudge to remember you. It is worth the effort to keep those old connections in any case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd be hesitant if you would have *only* recommendation letters from your Bachelor, but this is not the case.

Your first recommendation letter comes from your Master Thesis supervisor, which is good. On top of that, I would prefer to hear from someone else who has worked closely with you for an extended period of time. Hence, a supervisor from another thesis would be preferable to me over someone who taught a course and a seminar you attended (although that seminar also gives quite some insight in how you function, so I wouldn't knock a recommendation letter from that person either).

But look at it this way: two professors, from distinct universities, who both supervised you in a thesis process, with happy outcomes for all involved parties? I think that looks quite strong, actually.

Comment: Update: The professor of the Bachelor accepted to write a letter for me

Comment: @RubenCamposDelgado One step taken in the right direction. Good luck with the applications!

Answer (score 1):

Supervisor of BSc definitely would be a stronger option than some prof from the local university course. I don't see why wouldn't they remember you, really (it depends on the personality, of course, but most would) - on top of that, they would probably be delighted to hear from you and learn that you are on a good track towards PhD. Win/win!